# $5 File Hosting with API

Tags: api, cloud-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

Could anyone suggest a reliable file hosting service for personal use with developer API that will not cost more than five dollars. Thank you

Comment: What is an API? In relation to what?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to make any recommendations based on just "file hosting" requirements. How much data are you looking at, how much bandwidth is needed?

I've had a lot of success using [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) "Free Tier":

> 5 GB of Amazon S3 storage, 20,000 Get Requests, 2,000 Put Requests, and 15GB of data transfer out each month for one year.

For personal use you might be able to get away with not having to pay at all. Obviously, there's **TONS** of tools out there that take advantage of the API and you can even use it yourself.

One thing I noticed though, is that moving complete folders over isn't as straight forward as FTP, and I recommend a good S3 client to use instead of the web interface. Permissions can get a little tricky also if you're having a lot of users access the account. IAM helps alleviate some of those issues, however, support in most S3 clients is limited.

Also, check out Rackspace [CloudFiles](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/cloud_hosting_products/files/pricing/) which has usage dependent pricing. I've used their API also, and it's great!

Comment: I just came across this and though I would update it with what I finally chose. I found this provider [IDriveSync](http://www.idrivesync.com/) who give 150 GB for $5